# Assigning "+" key to ADD button in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, events, event-handling

I am making a calculator using WPF Application in MS Visual Studio 2010. I have made different buttons that are in a standard calculator and I have added button_Click methods on them. Now I also want to perform the same tasks as the button_Click method is performing by stroking the specific key.

For Example

I have "addButton_Click" method and it performs this:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _op = 1;    
        temp = displayPannel.Text;
        check = true;
    }
```

Now What If I wanted the "+" key to do the same thing in the calculator instead of using the mouse to click on "+" button. Also I want to use the numeric keys as well along with the mouse clicking. How can I do it?

Comment: Hook the key press event on the window

Comment: The only available methods it shows are KeyDown and KeyUp, also What should I write in KeyPress event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
  private void TextBox_PreviewKeyUp_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.OemPlus || e.Key == Key.Add)
            MessageBox.Show("Tada");
    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <TextBox Text="Hello" PreviewKeyUp="TextBox_PreviewKeyUp_1"/>
```

Comment: Lol, I answered first and it's more straightforward and I did not get the answer? It also covered the numeric events and your add key by OEM.

Comment: Yes, I tried choosing both of the answers as the right answer and it picked his. :p :D I'll pick yours if that makes you happy ^_^

Comment: Just remember that this solution only works when You have Focus on text box. If user clicks some button, and try to type new number it won't work till he click on TextBox. (That's why I mentioned Windows Calculator, it always let You type numbers even after clicking buttons). If that's all You need that's good, simple solutions are the best.

Answer (score 2):

You should extract method that does Add operation. It's not mandatory, but it's a good practice to call methods from handers, instead of having some large code inside handler, for example:

```
    private void addButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PerformAdd();
    }

    private void PerformAdd()
    {
        _op = 1;
        temp = displayPannel.Text;
        check = true;
    }
```

And Your actual question(I'm assuming here You want to create something like Windows Calculator):

1. Attach handler for PreviewKeyDown in MainWindow.xaml. It's preferable to use PreviewKeyDown, not KeyDown in Your case, as Preview events go from "outside to inside", meaning event will show up in MainWindow handler first, then in handlers for controls inside MainWindow, while normal events show up in inner classes first. Catching event in MainWindow first will allow You to process keypresses like '+' or '-' globally, without passing them to inner controls.
2. In handler You should check KeyCode, and call appropriate method, like this:

   ```
    private void Window_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Key == Key.OemPlus || e.Key == Key.Add)
                {
                    PerformAdd();
                    e.Handled = true;
                }
            }
   ```

As You can see there is e.Handled = true; line. If You mark event as handled it won't be passed to inner controls. You should mark it handled for 'operations' key presses, these keypresses shouldn't be passed as input to text box.

EDIT: As for numbers, You can do:

```
 if (e.Key == Key.D0 || e.Key == Key.NumPad0)
      textBox.Text = textBox.Text + "0";
```

Comment: Thank YOU SO MUCH! ^_^ It worked. How do I add the event to Numeric Keys?